# How to save values to a list in C#

Tags: c#

Currently I have a method for registration which is

```
Console.Write("What is your name? ");
name = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("How old are you? ");
age = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
Console.Write("What is your gender? M for Male, F for Female ");
gender = (Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a password: ");
    pw = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Confirm password:");
}
while (Console.ReadLine() != pw);
users.Add(name);
```

Let's say I want to lookup the name and load the age and gender associated with it when it was filled out, how do I tie that information to the name and then load it later?

Update:
By later I'm referring to when there are multiple registrants and I want to recall a specific one with his/her data. Similar to how an array would be able to load it through a for loop by

```
DB temp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
    if (users[i] != null)
    {
        temp = users[i];
        if (temp.CheckName() == name)
        break;
     }
}
if (temp.CheckName() == name)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        if (temp.LogMeIn(Console.ReadLine()) == true)
                LoggedIn(temp.CheckName());
    }
```

Comment: without database? use `static list`

Comment: This depends on more info like what does “later” mean? Regardless, for starters you would probably be better to keep a list of `User` (a class w/properties) somewhere rather than just a list of strings.

Comment: instead of using variables you can use class with properties name, age and gender. also password if u want. this will help your better

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy how do I do that? Sorry I'm pretty new to coding in general and I might have skipped a couple important things on the way.

Comment: @polors2 friend you have to go through basic things like these before you start coding. in SO we help you out if you need any corrections done. we cant teach you coding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to create a structure where we can organize our user information.
Therefore, we create the "User" struct like the following. For saving the gender, we create an enum, because it represents the gender better than the string which could basically contain anything.

```
public enum Gender
{
    Female,
    Male
}

public struct User
{
    public int Age { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Gender Gender { get; }
    public DateTime Time { get; }

    public User(DateTime time, Gender gender, string name, int age)
    {
        Time = time;
        Gender = gender;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

After we have these structures, we come back to your situation.
Currently you basically have the following variables:

```
var genderFromUser = "M";
var now = DateTime.Now;
var age = 25;
var name = "Willy";
```

The first thing we are going to do, is to transform the gender string you got from the user of your application to a Gender enum:

```
Gender gender;
if (genderFromUser == "M")
    gender = Gender.Male;
else
    gender = Gender.Female;
```

Afterwards, we have all the things we need to create a List of users, where we can save the users and retrieve them again.

```
//create list of users
var users = new List<User>();

//add a new user with the information above
users.Add(new User(
    time: now,
    gender: gender,
    name: name,
    age: age));

//... do other things.... for instance, add more users

//search user with a certain name in the list
var userWithNameWilly = users.Single(user => user.Name == "Willy");

// recover the information which has been saved
var retrievedAge = userWithNameWilly.Age;
var retrievedInsertionDate = userWithNameWilly.Time;
var retrievedGender = userWithNameWilly.Gender;

//do anything with the information
```

Comment: Thanks! I took Yogesh's advice and was able to apply your solution. It works now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 0):

Additional Security Hind: 
Calculate a pw-checksum/hash and use from this point the pw-checksum instead RAW Text.
Don't store passwords as RAW Text in variables, struct, class, Files or Database, or send/receive via Network. 
Those RAW Text pw can be easy used after collected by Data Spy. Make it safe.